# Model as a field of another model Django

Tags: python, django, database

I'm designing a payment system for a website, but I have trouble. A person can do a Payment and that Payment has a payment type, for example, debit card, credit card or PayPal. So, I need the possibility to add new payment options. The problem is I don't know how to link these two tables, I know that I need a third table with only the `payment_id` and the `payment_type_id` assigned. Is there a way to generate this with Django?

```
class PaymentType(models.Model):
    """Payment option available"""
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Payment(models.Model):
    class PaymentStatus(models.TextChoices):
        DONE = '1', "DONE"
        PENDENT = '2', "PENDENT"
        CANCELED = '3', "CANCELED"

    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=PaymentStatus.choices,
                              default=PaymentStatus.PENDENT)
    # payment type
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 0):

You may use a *many-to-one* relationship using a **ForeignKey** field from `Payment` class to the `PaymentType` class.

This field on the `Payment` class:

```
payment_type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This will create a relationship from a `Payment` to a `PaymentType`.

See [Many-To-One - Foreign Key Django Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Answer (score 0):

In Payment model add a field name "payment_type" and use foreign key field like below:

```
payment_type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name="payments", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```